# What do the '?', '.' and '+' symbols mean when I run 'who -aH'?

Tags: command-line, bash

What does the plus sign (`+`), question mark (`?`) and period (`.`) mean in the idle column when I run `who -aH`? I tried Google, but the results are all about regular expression and wildcards.

**EDIT**:

I figured out that the period (`.`) means that user is currently active. Still unsure of the other two.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From `info who`:

> After each login name print a character indicating the user's
>   message status:
>
> ```
> `+' allowing `write' messages
>  `-' disallowing `write' messages
>  `?' cannot find terminal device
> ```

Extending the same info to `IDLE`, it seems `?` indicates it cannot determine who much the time the user has been idle, and a `.` indicates the user (terminal) is currently active.